# How to inject Nginx fastcgi_param to Laravel Unit testing

Tags: laravel, nginx, phpunit

I have setup Laravel application which use  `fastcgi_param XXX YYY` from Nginx to initialize domain based functionalities. I can not find a way to inject `fastcgi_param` data into my Unit Test.

I have registered Laravel provider and I am getting **fastcgi_param** data from getenv('XXX'). Which is perfectly working on browser, but my challenge it inject them into Unit Tests.

I tried to update

```
<server name="XXX" value="YYY"/>
```

But unfortunatly it wont work.

When I do `dump($request->server())` it has no not found any reference for **XXX**

If you have any suggestions, I am so glad.

Comment: Try `<env name=... value=..>` instead of server

Comment: @apokryfos It is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have fixed, it thanks to @apokryfos.

What I did was

```
<env name="XXX" value="YYY"/>
```

instead of

```
<server name="XXX" value="YYY"/>
```